# Передача данных и обрыв связи

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

Приветствую всех! Есть 2 приложения, клиентское и серверное, между ними через интернет происходит передача текстовых данных от клиента серверу. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, с помощью чего лучше организовать передачу между ними чтобы при разрыве соединения можно было легко отловить этот разрыв и при подключении продолжить передачу с прошлого места.
Пробую сейчас на сокетах это реализовать, уперся в проблему что не могу отловить разрыв связи. Мой примерный код клиентской части:

```
try
{
    IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP.Text), 5555);
    Socket Connector = new Socket(EndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Connector.Connect(EndPoint);
    //Отправляем сообщение
    Byte[] SendBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Message);
    Connector.Send(SendBytes);
    Connector.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Код серверной части:

```
TcpListener Listen = new TcpListener(5555);
Listen.Start();
Socket ReceiveSocket;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        //Пришло сообщение
        ReceiveSocket = Listen.AcceptSocket();
        Byte[] Receive = new Byte[256];
        using (MemoryStream MessageR = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Работа с данными
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

С такими кодом при недоступном сервере клиент пытается слать несколько сообщений и вылетают несколько ошибок.